# Application of Cauchy theorem to prove normality of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group $o(G)=pq$, where $p,q$ are both distinct prime numbers. Let $H<G$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $o(H)=p$. I want to show that $H$ is normal in $G$. My argument goes as follows. First we observe that based on Cauchy theorem for groups there exist $a,b \in G$ such that $o(a)=p$ and $o(b)=q$. Now we know that $o(ab)=LCM(o(a), o(b))=pq$, so $G$ is cyclic and $ab$ generates $G$. If $G$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian and as every subgroup of an abelian group is normal it follows that $H$ is normal in $G$. Can someone verify if this argument is valid?

Comment: It is not true in general that the order of a product of elements is the lcm of their respective orders. Also, you should have been very much alarmed when you seemed to prove that every group of order $pq$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument can't possibly be right since what you try to prove is, in general, false. For example, take

$$G=S_3\;,\;\;|G|=2\cdot 3\;,\;\;H=\{\;(1)\,,\,(12)\;\}\le G\;\;\text{ but }\;\;H\rlap{\;\;/}\lhd G$$

What is true is that if $\,|G|=pq\;,\;p>q\,$ primes **and** $\;p\neq 1\pmod q\;$ then any Sylow $\,q$-subgroup of $\,G\,$ is normal.

And your proof begins with problem at $\,ord(ab)=LCM(ord(a)\,,\,ord(b))\,$ , since this isn't true in general (it though is true if $\,ab=ba\,$ and $\;gcd(ord(a)\,,\,ord(b))=1\;$ ), and thus you can not deduce $\,G\,$ is cyclic, which again is false in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful when you say $o(ab)=LCM(o(a), o(b))$ as this result doesn't hold in general. For example, consider the group $(\{1,-1\},\times)$. We have $o(1)=1$ and $o(-1)=2$ but $1=-1\times-1$ and $LCM(2,2)=2$

HINT: If $o(H)=p$ what can you say about $H$? Similarly, what can you say about the subgroup of order $q$?